# Custom resolution isn't showing up in the settings menu

Tags: virtualization, display-resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu on a VM and I noticed that my screen inside of the VM was too small. So, after a quick google search I found out you can change this by using the `xrandr` command to create a custom resolution.

Then I created one with 1920x1080, I got no errors during the process but afterwards I noticed that it wouldn't show up in my resolution menu.
I checked if it was saved by executing the `xrandr` command again and it said it had saved so I'm really confused.

Comment: What program are you using to run the VM?  Is it VirtualBox, VMWare, or something else?

Comment: I'm using VMware

Comment: Do you have to VMWare additions installed?  Used VMWare a little bit in the past, but I don't remember how to install the additions.  I know there were some, though.  Look around the menus of VMWare and look for an option such as "Mount Guest Additions ISO"